# Display Dataset as comma separated values group by the serial number

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a dataset in SQL Server. I want to display the end result as comma separated values group by the serial number.

[image]

The end result of my select query should in this format

```
    1 Maths     Raj,Alan
    2 English   Rahul,Harry
    3.Science   Percy,Ron'
```

> Blockquote

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  -

**Sample Table & Data**

```
declare @data table
(
 SerialID int,
 Subjects varchar(50),
 Students varchar(50)
 )


insert into @data
(SerialID, Subjects, Students) 
values
(1,'Maths', 'Raj' ),
(1, 'Maths', 'Alan'),
(2,'English', 'Rahil'),
(3, 'Science', 'Percy'),
(2,'English', 'Harry'),
(3,'Science', 'Ron')
```

**Query**

```
  Select SerialID,
    Subjects,
     STUFF ((
        select ','+ Students
        From @data b
        where a.SerialID = b.SerialID
        For xml path(''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') FirstName
    From @data a
    Group by SerialID, Subjects
```